# Difference between various similar packages 14.04 repo

Tags: 14.04, gnome, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome

There are some similar packages in the Ubuntu 14.04 repositories:

- [`gnome-desktop-environment`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/gnome-desktop-environment) (since this is a transitional meta-package see also its dependency [`gnome`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/gnome))
- [`ubuntu-gnome-desktop`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/ubuntu-gnome-desktop)
- [`ubuntu-desktop`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/amd64/ubuntu-desktop)

What is the difference in these three?

Comment: I added some links to the package descriptions (and release histories) to your question. You could get the same information with `apt-cache show <PACKAGE>`. Is this what you're looking for or do you want to know something else about them?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. I think ubuntu-desktop is the default desktop that we get with ubuntu (i.e. with unity on top of gnome). And gnome-desktop-environment is pure gnome DE with all its software packages. And ubuntu-gnome-desktop is gnome DE optimised for ubuntu but is very similar to pure gnome.

Comment: That is correct. Would you like to [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) based on that comment?

Comment: @David his answers would already be superseded by mine - which explains what each package does.

Comment: You are right @David. Thanks for the answer. But it's very technical. I have explained it in simple words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're each completely different packages, and while 'similar' in the sense they're metapackages, they are vastly different from each other.

`ubuntu-desktop` is a metapackage for the standard Ubuntu Desktop and its suite of apps the Ubuntu Desktop ISOs install (Unity, the selected software suites, etc.); it's been present in the repos since Ubuntu Desktop was created.  You can see all it 'depends' on (and installs) at it's listing on `packages.ubuntu.com` ([this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-desktop) shows the Xenial version of the package; [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-desktop) shows the Trusty version).

`ubuntu-gnome-desktop` is similar, but specifically for the entire Ubuntu GNOME Desktop ISOs' installed software and has only been available since the Ubuntu GNOME flavor has been around (pure GNOME without Unity, etc.).  ([this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/ubuntu-gnome-desktop) shows the Xenial version of the package and its dependencies on `packages.ubuntu.com` like above; [this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-gnome-desktop) shows the Trusty version of the package)

`gnome-desktop-environment` is actually a transitional package, left in place for 'upgrade' compatibility for older operating systems to newer operating systems.  It is actually a metapackage in 14.04 (and not later) that just installs the `gnome` package.  ([this link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnome-desktop-environment) to `packages.ubuntu.com` shows this).  This is handled differently later on, so that transitional package is not needed anymore (probably just by installing `gnome` or similar in later versions).